# How to get textbox widget inside grid to work property?

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have placed a textbox widget inside grid cell by using formatter. However, I cannot move my cursor around nor select text inside the textbox.

E.g.
http://jsfiddle.net/g33m9/69/

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the column as **'editable'** so that the Grid component will know how to handle keypressed events. So a modification to the layout is in order

#### from

```
var layout = [[
        {name: 'Column 1', field: 'col1'},
        {name: 'Column 2', field: 'col2', width:'200px', formatter: func}
    ]];
```

#### to

```
var layout = [[
        {name: 'Column 1', field: 'col1'},
        {name: 'Column 2', field: 'col2', width:'200px', formatter: func, editable: true}
    ]];
```

Edit state activates by doubleclick.

Now, OP wants it to be a fully bloated widget, popping up in the editable state. For this to be scaleable up with any number of rows/columns i will restrict this to the *edit* state, so that the value simply shows text but once double-clicked it will pop a FilteringSelect. Same principle goes with the dijit widget ValidationTextBox.

Currently (1.7.2) the possible celltypes are:
dojox.grid.cells.Bool
dojox.grid.cells.ComboBox
dojox.grid.cells.DateTextBox
dojox.grid.cells.Select

Catch me SEO:

## example of custom dojox.grid cellType widget - semi-programmatic

#### First step - create some data

```
var i = 0,
data = {
    identifier: 'id',
    items: [
      { id: i, value: 'val'+i++},
      { id: i, value: 'val'+i++},
      { id: i, value: 'val'+i++},
      { id: i, value: 'val'+i++}
    ]
},
// The item label which holds visible value and which holds the value to represent
searchAttr = 'value',
valueAttr = data.identifier,
// The store to use for select widget
store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ data: data }),
// And the options, reassembling the valid options we will present in dropdown
// Used when cellType is dojox.grid.cells.Select to name the allowable options
options = [];
dojo.forEach(data.items, function(it) { options.push(it[searchAttr])});
```

#### Tricky part - Define a cellType

Lets extend the existing `dojox.grid.cells.Cell`, it has two key features - an edit-state-formatter and the default-formatter. The default would work just fine. Last but not least, we'll override the '_finish' function allthough allow the Cell to process its own definition too.

```
var whenIdle = function( /*inContext, inMethod, args ...*/ ) {
    setTimeout(dojo.hitch.apply(dojo, arguments), 0);
};

var FilteringSelectCell = declare("dojox.grid.cells.FilteringSelect", [dojox.grid.cells.Cell], {
    options: null,
    values: null,

    _destroyOnRemove: true,
    constructor: function(inCell){
        this.values = this.values || this.options;
    },

    selectMarkupFactory: function(cellData, rowIndex) {
        var h = ['<select data-dojo-type="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" id="deleteme' + rowIndex + '" name="foo">'];
        for (var i = 0, o, v;
        ((o = this.options[i]) !== undefined) && ((v = this.values[i]) !== undefined); i++) {
            v = v.replace ? v.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;') : v;
            o = o.replace ? o.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;') : o;
            h.push("<option", (cellData == v ? ' selected' : ''), ' value="' + v + '"', ">", o, "</option>");
        }
        h.push('</select>');
        return h;
    },
    textMarkupFactory: function(cellData, rowIndex) {
        return ['<input class="dojoxGridInput" id="deleteme' + rowIndex + '" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" type="text" value="' + cellData + '">']

    },
    // @override
    formatEditing: function(cellData, rowIndex) {

        this.needFormatNode(cellData, rowIndex);
        var h = (cellData == "W1")
            ? this.textMarkupFactory(cellData, rowIndex)
            : this.selectMarkupFactory(cellData, rowIndex);
        // a slight hack here, i had no time to figure out when the html would actually be inserted to the '<td>' so.. Use 'debugger' statement and track function to hook into
        whenIdle(function() {
            dojo.parser.parse(dojo.byId('deleteme' + rowIndex).parentNode);
            var w = dijit.byId('deleteme' + rowIndex);
            w.focus()

        });
        return h.join('');
    },
    // clean up avoiding multiple widget definitions 'hanging'
    _finish: function(inRowIndex) {
        this.inherited(arguments)
        dijit.byId('deleteme' + inRowIndex).destroy();
    },
    // needed to read the value properly, will work with either variant
    getValue: function(rowIndex) {
        var n = this.getEditNode(rowIndex);
        n = dijit.getEnclosingWidget(n);
        return n.get("value");
    }
});
```

#### Last bit, a new layout

```
var layout = [[
      { name: 'Column 1', field: 'col1' },
      { name: 'Column 2', field: 'col2', 
        cellType: FilteringSelectCell, options: options, editable: true
      }
]];
```

**Running sample here** http://jsfiddle.net/dgbxw/1/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but it didn't help in my situation. When you double click, the functionality of the widget will be lost; for example, if I have a validation text box or combobox, after double click the validation won't work or the combobox will disappear.

Comment: ok, the more indepth answer then - the grid is limited to three types of cells, as-is. For you to achieve a perfect ValidationTextBox immitation in a cell you would have to extend the `dojox.grid.cells.Cell`. I will give a sample, starting with the `dojox.grid.cells.Select`

Comment: Can you expand your answer further. The way I am doing it is kind of non-standard. I need to have different widget displaying in the SAME column based on value type in the field.
E.g.
For column 2, row 1, I want to display a combobox.
For column 2, row 2, I want to display a validation box.
For column 2, row 3, I want to display a check box etc..

The way you're describing will force all rows of the same column to be the same type.

Comment: The way I am doing it right now is not to specify a cell type. Then in the formatter:
if value type is x, create [var comboBox = new dijit.form.ComboBox] and return that variable; if value type is y, create [var textBox = new dijit.form.ValidationTextBox] and return that variable. That way, I can have different widgets showing in the SAME column. HOWEVER, I get weird behaviors such as I cannot position my cursor in the textbox etc.. (as you can see in http://jsfiddle.net/g33m9/69/). Do you think I am working towards a dead end? Any workaround at all?

Comment: yes, i think - kinda dead end.. The design, youre looking for, is a morphing layout, it will get quite tricky to catch it at the right moment. Instead you should make the custom cellType create either 1: a select or 2: an input textfield in the formatEditing function.

Comment: Thanks again for your extended answer. Does your solution allow me to to show different widgets in the SAME column. For simplicity, let's say row 1 field.value=1, on column [2], I want to display a validationbox, if row 2 field.value=2, on the same column [2], I want to display a combobox. Do you think you can add this main functionality to your solution? (if you can create a http://jsfiddle, it would be a bonus; if not it's cool too). Thanks

Comment: Yea, its simple enough, the cell formatter returns html and the above design simply runs dojo parser on it. While using a dijit.form widget its also simple enough to get the value out. In fact, you could implement just about any widget cellType :D

Comment: Your new posted solution looks very promising, let me try it out in my real project, and I'll report back, thanks!

Comment: Your solution is amazing, very advanced. Most importantly, it works! I've been stuck for weeks..so I really appreciate the time you've put into this solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: would love to simply leave a **;)** if only it was enough chars hehe